# Creating 3 level (multilevel) drop down in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

How to create 3 level drop down options in angular. We can make use of angular-material?

```
<h4>mat-select</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Pokemon</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="pokemonControl">
    <mat-option>-- None --</mat-option>
    <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of pokemonGroups" [label]="group.name"
                  [disabled]="group.disabled">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let pokemon of group.pokemon" [value]="pokemon.value">
        {{pokemon.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-optgroup>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>





The above code has two level. But how can we make it to the  3 level. 
   Something like, 
   Label1 -> Option1 -> option1.1 and option1.2  
   Label1 -> Option2 -> option1.1 and option1.2 
   Label2 -> Option2 -> option1.1 and option1.2
```

[image: See the drop down image attached]

`VolumeMetrics -> [IOPS, Kbps] -> [Read, Write]`
How to achieve such sort of drop down with 3 levels?

Any help will be appreciated?

We can make use of either html/angular, but it would be good to make use of angular material?

Comment: Take a look at the last example from here: https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples. Maybe you can implement it using the menu component.

Comment: Thanks Paul for the suggestion. But the flaw is that it does not behave as `drop down` and how to retrieve the value out of button click?

Comment: hi any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

consider to combine - mat-select & mat-menu components to implement the dropdown menu such that it can accommodate multi levels as we expected above.

demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-menu

Here I'm using mat-select as disabled and on the dropdown click showing multi level mat-menu. once user select any item from the menu we are setting the value to the dropdown.

I know this is somewhat unconventional approach, however if it satisfy the requirements you can consider to go with this approach.